# Error: Invalid Use of Void Expression in C

Tags: c

I'm getting an "invalid use of void expression" error regarding the following function:

```
void remove_data(char* memory, char* bitmap, int pos)
{
    int i;

    i = (int)test_bit(bitmap, pos-1);

    if(i != 0)
    {
        memory[pos-1] = NULL;
        toggle_bit(bitmap, pos-1);
    }
}
```

Now from what I've read on other threads regarding this similar issue this error pops up when the programmer uses something within the function that will generate an output.  However, I'm failing to see what would cause that in the code I've written.

Edit to add:

The toggle bit function used in it is also type void and doesn't return a value.

```
void test_bit(char * bitmap, int pos)
{
    int bit;

    bit = bitmap[pos/8] & (1<<(pos%8));
    printf("%d\n", &bit);
}
```

I commented the printf line in test_bit but the error is still there.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error, and what's the declaration of `test_bit` and `toggle_bit`?

Comment: toggle_bit seems irrelevant, should show definition of test_bit

Comment: void test_bit does have a printf, I was focused on finding the error within remove_data that I completely forgot to check the functions it called.

Comment: @Kali: And there you have your answer...

Comment: And what should be the result of casting no return type to `int`?

Comment: Well now I feel silly for asking that, thanks guys.

Answer (score 9):

> However, I'm failing to see what would cause that in the code I've written.

Me too, because I don't think you have posted the relevant code.  Regardless, I think this is probably your problem:

```
i = (int)test_bit(bitmap, pos-1);
```

Please show us the signature for `test_bit`.  I'm guessing it returns `void` or you have forward declared it somewhere and accidentally wrote:

```
void test_bit(char*, int);
```

Since the function returns `void` (i.e., nothing) you cannot then proceed to cast the return value (which is nothing) to an `int` as you are doing, it makes no sense and is illegal.

EDIT: You have verified in the comments that `test_bit` is in fact declared to return `void`, so that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since test_bit is void, you may not use its return (as in `i = (int)test_bit(bitmap, pos-1);`) -- there *is* no return value.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
 i = (int)test_bit(bitmap, pos-1);
```

Why have a cast?

Seems a bit wrong when the function is

```
void test_bit(char * bitmap, int pos)
{
    int bit;

    bit = bitmap[pos/8] & (1<<(pos%8));
    printf("%d\n", &bit);
}
```

You can't convert a void into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**Obvious**     Solution: Don't assign results of function returning void.

**Non-Obvious** Solution: Don't nest function calls, and you are less likely
to be looking in all of the wrong spots, thinking the compiler is broken.

```
#include <stdio.h> //:for: printf(...)

void YOUR_MISTAKE_ACTUALLY_HERE();
void  MyFunc( void );
void* WRAPPED_MyFunc( int, int, int );


int main( void ){
    printf("[BEG:main]\n");


    void* HW = NULL;
    HW = WRAPPED_MyFunc(  //:<---So you check this, but it looks fine.
        1
    ,   YOUR_MISTAKE_ACTUALLY_HERE()
    ,   3
    );; //:<--- compiler says "Invalid Use Of Void Expression" Here.

    if( HW ){ /** NOOP **/ };


    printf("[END:main]\n");
} 

    void YOUR_MISTAKE_ACTUALLY_HERE(){ }

    //:Pretend this function is fetched from DLL.
    //:Casting all DLL functions initially to void(*pfn)void
    //:in a lookup table, then re-casting later.
    void MyFunc( void ){

        return;

    }//[;]//

    typedef  
        void* 
        (* MyFunc_TYPEDEF)(            

            int a
        ,   int b
        ,   int c

        );

    void*
    WRAPPED_MyFunc(

        int a
    ,   int b
    ,   int c

    ){


               MyFunc_TYPEDEF
        fun =( MyFunc_TYPEDEF)
               MyFunc;

        void* ret=( fun(

            a
        ,   b
        ,   c

        ));

        return( 
            (void*)
            ret 
        );;

    }//:Func
```